# How to let mobile navigation menu close when link is clicked?

Tags: php, menus, css, child-theme

I am using a wordpress theme and i wanted to change the navigation menu to a one-page navigation menu. I already made everything work except when i am using a mobile the menu does not close when i click the menu-items. All the menu links start with #. I am using a child-theme and want to add a function to the function.php file that closes the window when menu-item is clicked.

Here is my function.php file.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'PRANAYAMA_YOGA_THEME_VERSION'; // 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
```

Is it possible to do this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: the above mention code is not useful , share the site url.

Answer (score 0):

I would use javascript (or jQuery) to detect when the menu item is clicked and close the menu.

```
$( '.menu-item' ).on( 'click', function(e){
    e.preventdefault();

    // add a class to target with CSS and close the menu or do animation to close it
} );
```